# How to create a binary output if a value is found in a separate list excel

Tags: excel, binary, lookup

I'm new to this forum.  I am trying to write a formula with only 1 or 0 as outcomes.  I have 100,000 patients identified by hospital number in column B, and a separate sheet with x number of patients with a certain diagnosis.  I want to create a new column with yes/no (1/0) values depending if the patient identifier in column B is found in the range on my separate sheet.  Please excuse me if this is very straightforward. I'm new to this!

Answer (score 1):

Use the MATCH function in combination with IF: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH([Patient Identifier], [Range on Separate Sheet], 0)), 0, 1)`. The MATCH function will return an error if the value sought is not found in the range.

Answer (score 0):

The `MATCH` function returns the specific error value #N/A if it fails, so you are better of using that instead of covering for any error.

Assuming your Seperate List is in the column A of sheet 2, you can have something like this for row 2:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!A:A,0)), 0, 1)
```

which basically means:

1. Try and `MATCH` the value in `Sheet1!B2`in `Sheet2!A:A`.
2. If you get a `#N/A` error value, then you did not find a match, put `0`
3. Else you got a match, put `1`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler version of the above formula mentioned by manimatters.

```
=--Not(ISNA(MATCH(Sheet1!B2,{Patient Column other Sheet},0)))
```

Copy this into the column right of column B in your "Patient Identifier" Sheet.